# Optional setter

Tags: php

How can I set a specific setter inside of a child class to be optional

I have a web page build with PHP that prints a recursive objects array, I have a parent class called Person and a child class called Teachers.

Now the teachers can also teach another teacher, I have divided my teachers with the following types "Master, Senior, Junior", and as a matter of fact I already solve that problem, I can see an array of objects within an array of objects, something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Teacher Object
        (
            [subject:Teacher:private] => Matematicas
            [teacherType:Teacher:private] => Master
            [teachers:Teacher:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Teacher Object
                        (
                            [subject:Teacher:private] => Matematicas 2
                            [teacherType:Teacher:private] => Senior
                            [teachers:Teacher:private] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Teacher Object
                                        (
                                        [subject:Teacher:private] => Ciancias 1
                                        [teacherType:Teacher:private] => Junior
                                        [teachers:Teacher:private] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                        [id:Person:private] => 7
                                        [name:Person:private] => Pedro
                                        [nickname:Person:private] => PedroBoy
                                    )

                            )
```

I imagine you get the idea, my problem is that the junior teacher does not receive any teachers array, because he is a jnuior teacher and he can't teach teachers yet. But if I write nothing on it, it will launch an error saying that the teachers array of junior teachers is undifined and it will assign an empty teachers array object to it.

Is there any way to nake that specific setter optional?.

Here is my PHP Code:

```
class Teacher extends Person{

    private $subject = '';
    private $teacherType = '';
    private $teachers = array();

    public function __construct($data) {
        parent::__construct($data);
        $this->setSubject($data["subject"]);
        //OPTIONAL
        $this->setTeachers($data["teachers"]);
        $this->setTeacherType($data["type"]);
    }
```

?>

Comment: Just do not call the setter if you do not need it....

Comment: `if (isset($data['teachers'])) {
 $this->setTeachers($data["teachers"]);
}`

Comment: Im already tried and yes, the error disappears but still, the junior teacher appears with an empty array. I dont want that, the junior teacher should not have that property

Comment: then you are looking for a completely different data model. junior teacher and senior teacher should be different classes.

Comment: @BenjaminGil - You shouldn't care that you have an empty array for Teachers for a case that should not have teachers...not worth creating another model in my opinion, but as yivi stated, that's essentially what you're asking for.

Comment: ...there are actual benefits to having the empty array there, for example, you can call a `foreach` on the teachers attribute for any Teacher Object without adding conditional logic (in many more places) - however, if you needed to check if it were there for some reason, with values, you can still run `if (!empty($teacher.teachers))`

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a simple if statement?

```
class Teacher extends Person
{

    private $subject = '';
    private $teacherType = '';
    private $teachers = array();

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        parent::__construct($data);
        $this->setSubject($data["subject"]);
        if (isset($data['teachers']))
            $this->setTeachers($data["teachers"]);
        $this->setTeacherType($data["type"]);
    }
```